# Tracking the number of put/get methods on Map using the Java API

Tags: java

how can we track the number of calls on the get and put methods on a Map?.

I have seen somewhere about `JProfiler`, but I must say that I would like to know if the problem can be solved using the **Java API itself**.

Comment: wrap the map in your own class, and implelemt a counter on the calls

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options come to mind.

- If you don't want to change the source code of your application then introspection is the way to go. Use a profiler for method invocations and see how much these methods are invoked. VisualVM, JProfiler and others.
- If you don't want to use an external application that needs to hook in then look into aspect oriented programming. For example AspectJ. Configure an aspect for those method entries and log the results.
- If you want to log the calls from your own API then you can write a wrapper around the Map implementation of your choie and log the invocations. Of course you need to your custom wrapper then for all Map related operations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to go for a full Java implementation, just implement a wrapper class with a particular counter that's incremented evety time a method is invoked.

If you want to organize your code better and have a *central "repository"* of application metadata, I suggest you implement the [Observer Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) by making the *Observable* object a wrapper of the maps you'll keep track of, notifying this central observer about a certain operation being called.

This central observer will, then, keep track of all of its managed objects with detailed counters of the particular operations you want to keep track of.